# Drawing a path with n vertices in XY-Pic

Tags: graphs, xy-pic, xymatrix

I am trying to draw a path graph using XY-Pic, and I would like to show that there's n vertices in a certain point, with a simple dashed / dotted line between two vertices, and an underbrace (or overbrace, doesn't particularly matter) covering this section. See a scanned handwritten copy for what I mean:

[image: Path showing a section with n vertices]

I'm struggling with two things: 
1) Getting a nicely drawn dashed section between the two vertices 
2) Producing the underbrace with the text.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
*{\bullet} \ar@{-}[r]*{} & *{\bullet} \ar@{-}[r]*{} & *{\bullet} \ar@{--}[r]*{} & \ar@{--}[r]*{} & *{\bullet}
}\]

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get a nicer looking dashed (or dotted) line that is longer than the standard line, and any nice way to get the underbrace included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is my humble and "primitive" proposal with a mix of combinations. I hope to have understood your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
*{\bullet} \ar@{-}[r]*{} & *{\bullet} \ar@{-}[r]*{} & *{\bullet} \ar@{--}[r]*{} & \ar@{--}[r]*{}_{\mbox{$\mkern-50mu\underbrace{\phantom{\scriptscriptstyle abcdefghfdhdhdhj}}_{\text{$n-$\! vertices}}$}} & *{\bullet}
}\]

\end{document}
```